# Importing a certificate to Azure key vaullt: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-keyvault

I am trying to import a .PFX file (first converted to base64 file), into Azure Keyvault, with the code below.

However I get the error: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Conflict'

There are absolutely no other certificates on the Azure KeyVault.

```
 public async Task ImportCertificate(string base64FileCertFile, string CertPasswordText, string name)
        {
            AzureServiceTokenProvider azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
            KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

            Message = "Your application description page.";
            int retries = 0;

            //byte[] fileData = null;
            //using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(request.Files[0].InputStream))
            //{
            //        fileData = binaryReader.ReadBytes(request.Files[0].ContentLength);
            //}

            //var base64EncodedCertificate = Convert.ToBase64String(fileData);
            bool retry = false;
            try
            {
                /* The below do while logic is to handle throttling errors thrown by Azure Key Vault. It shows how to do exponential backoff which is the recommended client side throttling*/
                do
                {
                    long waitTime = Math.Min(GetWaitTime(retries), 2000000);
                    var result = await keyVaultClient.ImportCertificateAsync(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VaultUrl"].ToString(), name, base64FileCertFile, CertPasswordText);

                    Message = result.Id;
                    retry = false;
                }
                while (retry && (retries++ < 10));
             }
            /// <exception cref="KeyVaultErrorException">
            /// Thrown when the operation returned an invalid status code
            /// </exception>
            catch (KeyVaultErrorException keyVaultException)
            {
                Message = keyVaultException.Message;
                if ((int)keyVaultException.Response.StatusCode == 429)
                    retry = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please remove ```try catch``` module to get the detail of exception or use the fiddler to catch request to get the error in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the issue, according to my research, when a KV certificate is created for the first time, an addressable key and secret is also created with the same name as that of the certificate. If the name is already in use, then the operation will fail with an http status code of 409 (conflict). For more details, please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/create-certificate#first-creation).  So  I suggest you change the name.